# swift hiding label when a button is pressed

Tags: swift, button, label

I have created my own label and my own button. Now when the page loads the label hides as I want but when i click the button it does not show up as it supposed to do, in fact it does not do anything. How can I fix this problem which is making label show when i press the button?

```
 @IBOutlet var thumbsUpButtonaPressed : UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "00000"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

       label.hidden = true




   let buttona = UIButton()
        buttona.frame = CGRectMake(0.772 * view.bounds.width, 0.32 * view.bounds.height, 22, 22)
        buttona.layer.cornerRadius = 0.04 * view.bounds.width
        buttona.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        buttona.setImage(UIImage(named:"A.png"), forState: .Normal)
        buttona.addTarget(self, action: "thumbsUpButtonaPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)


     func thumbsUpButtonaPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

            label.hidden = false



    }
  }
```

Answer (score 25):

I am using below code on `swift 3`

```
label.isHidden = true // hide
label.isHidden = false // show
```

you can use `isHidden` with other ui objects, see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39982054/1746258) also

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something in viewDidLoad you are creating a new label

```
 var label = ...
```

you are not using the IBOutlet Property like

```
 label = ...
```

Also are you sure your brackets are correct because it looks like your buttonPressed method is nested inside viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Create an IBAction:

```
@IBAction func thumbsUpButtonaPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    label.hidden = false
}
```

Then connect it with your button by cmd + drag on the button to the action:

[image]

**Swift 5 Update**

```
@IBAction func thumbsUpButtonaPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    label.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change:

```
label.alpha = 1.0 // show
label.alpha = 0.0 // hide
```

Try to correct your function with:

```
func thumbsUpButtonaPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
            print("button was pressed")
            label.hidden = false
            label.setNeedDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create normal IBAction for your button:

```
@IBAction func thumbsUpButtonaPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

  label.hidden = false
}
```