# Toggling UITextField to show and hide in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, show-hide

I'm trying to hide a username textfield when toggling over to login from register and show it again when toggling back. I'm programming the UI in and I would like to figure out how you can hide a textfield, I'm new to swift and I think there are two places I could insert code to hide the username textfield. If not please tell me, Thanks!

Image of what I am trying to hide. [image: Username Textfield Still Showing when login is toggled]

Here in the UISegmentedControl

```
lazy var loginRegisterSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Login", "Register"])
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegisterChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()
```

Or here in the HeightAnchor Change

```
nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1/3)
        nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this to set when you want the `UITextField` hidden or visible depending on your application structure

You can do it this way to make the field **visible**:

`myTextField.isHidden = false`

and this way to make it **hidden**:

`myTextField.isHidden = true`

Answer (score 1):

> Updated for Swift :

*Used below simple code :*

// UIButtonOutlet

```
@IBOutlet var confirmPassTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var confirmPassButton: UIButton!
```

//IBAction Method

```
@IBAction func actionOnConfirmButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if (confirmPassTextField.isSecureTextEntry == true){
        confirmPassTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
        confirmPassButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "show_pass"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        confirmPassButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hide_pass"), for: .normal)
        confirmPassTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
}
```

Note: "show_pass" and "hide_pass" - UIImage Name